# APACHE POI setting cell style clears existing date format

Tags: java, excel, date, apache-poi

I am new to Java programming and this is my first post so hopefully it's a valid question. I have searched the archives but can't find a suitable answer.

My class is reading and validating a spreadsheet. Cells in error are set to a style with a red background, valid cells are given a style with no backround. This all works fine until a date cell is encountered. The setCellStyle statement appears to be clearing the date formatting. Can anyone advise me how to prevent this please?

So, when viewing the cell in Excel to begin with, it shows 25/08/20.

After updating the style to background red in my program, then going back into Excel, the cell shows in red but with a numeric value like 92345678.0000 (I can't remember the exact value now).

Here's the relevant bit of code:

```
XSSFCellStyle styleBad = wb.createCellStyle();
XSSFCellStyle styleGood = wb.createCellStyle();
styleGood.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.NO_FILL);
styleBad.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
styleBad.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
if (!validateCell(cell, tca[cx], cellValues)) {
  cell.setCellStyle(styleBad);
  errorMessage += ("Cell " + (cx + 1) + " " + cellValues.cellMessage + ". ");
  wbValid = false;
  }
else {
  cell.setCellStyle(styleGood);                        Mucks up date formatting??                                                                     
}
```

Comment: Cell Styles include data formatting. So, you need to copy the data format pattern

Answer (score 2):

The number format patterns are part of the cell style. So as you are setting the cell style new, you also set number format patterns to default.

You could using `CellUtil` to **add** properties to the existent cell style instead of setting it new. The method `CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties` is able adding new cell style properties but remaining the cell style properties which are already present for the cell.

```
...
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
...

if (!validateCell(cell, tca[cx], cellValues)) {
  properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  properties.put(CellUtil.FILL_PATTERN, FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  properties.put(CellUtil.FILL_FOREGROUND_COLOR, IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
  CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, properties); 
  errorMessage += ("Cell " + (cx + 1) + " " + cellValues.cellMessage + ". ");
  wbValid = false;
}
else {
  properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  properties.put(CellUtil.FILL_PATTERN, FillPatternType.NO_FILL);
  CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, properties);       
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks Axel, that's really helpful. Sadly though this is running on an IBM i, which only supports Java 8 and therefore only POI 3.9. Therefore I have had to use setStyleProperty, so no big deal really. I still haven't quite got it working, the error cell doesn't fill until you click in it, and then it's filled black rather than red! I will hopefully figure this out myself in the next day or two.

Comment: @Russell Catchpole: Not clear why that old (really ancient) `apache poi 3.9` shall be used. But the requirement `Java 8` cannot be the reason. All current `apache poi` versions are running on `Java 8`.